# Using define_method inside a Module that gets included inside a Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, metaprogramming

I got something like this:

```
module MyModule
    define_method(:foo){ puts "yeah!" }
end

class User
  include MyModule
end
```

But this does not work as intended... They are not defined.
Also I need to use the Module because I want to distinguish the Methods from there from the normal User Methods. Which I do like this:

```
MyModule.instance_methods
```

Please help .. what am I missing?
I also tried:

```
module MyModule
  (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
    define_method(:foo){ puts "yeah!" }
  end
end
```

which also doesn't work :/

to clarify ... I would like to use:

```
User.first.foo
```

not

```
MyModule.foo
```

Comment: Looks ok to me:
    `module MyModule; end`
    `=> nil`
    `class User; include MyModule; end`
    `=> User`
    `module MyModule; define_method(:foo){ puts "yeah!" }; end`
    `=> #<Proc:0x0000000101fd83e0@(irb):3>`
    `User.new.foo`
    `yeah!`
    `=> nil`
    `MyModule.instance_methods` 
    `=> ["foo"]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use the `extend self` trick:

```
module MyModule
  define_method(:foo){ puts "yeah!" }

  extend self
end
```

This has the effect of making this module both a mixin and a singleton.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have a class method the following will work

```
module MyModule
    define_singleton_method(:foo){ puts "yeah!" }
end

MyModule.foo
# >> yeah!
```